# Why is there no \mudimendef primitive?

Tags: math-mode, tex-core, dimensions

The TeXbook defines in chapter 24 (page 270 in my edition) the notion of *`<dimen>`*, *`<skip>`*, *`<mudimen>`* and *`<muskip>`*, the first two being used in horizontal and vertical mode, while the other ones are used in math mode.

However this parallel between math mode and other modes is broken by registers: only `\dimendef`, `\skipdef` and `\muskipdef` exist, and not `\mudimendef`. Similarly, `\dimen 0`, `\skip 0` and `\muskip 0` exist, but not `\mudimen 0`.

The only primitive that manipulates mudimens seems to be `\mkern`. Why are *`<mudimens>`* so special?

EDIT: extra question. I'm asking this because I try to be able to grab the argument of any primitive. To grab a *`<dimen>`*, for instance, one can use `\newdimen\MyDimen` and `\afterassignment\DoSomethingWithMyDimen \MyDimen=`. Given that TeX does not have *`<mudimen>`* parameters, I cannot use the same trick for that. I cannot use a muskip either, because it may mistakenly grab a stretch or shrink part which `\mkern` would stop at. It may be that I can use a `\count` register in some cases, but not all: how could I distinguish between cases like `\mkern 1mu` and `\mkern \MyMuskip` (with automatic coercion)?

Comment: There is only one unit `mu` for `\mkern`. Thus a `\count` would suffie. I guess this is why there isn't `\mudimen` register.

Comment: @Leo Liu: that's a great reason. How could I then grab a `<mudimen>` argument? Can you think of a way to grab exactly what `\mkern` would grab as its argument? See edit.

Comment: I've no idea. But I guess you can change your desired syntax and use a count register without problems.

Comment: @Leo Liu: I'm reading arbitrary TeX code, and expanding fully all macros, then looking at whatever primitive is in front of me and doing what TeX would do with it. So I can't really change my syntax since it's that of TeX. I think I'll settle down for a muskip, despite the fact that it can in some cases grab too much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the answer is that there's no `\mudimen` register. :) So there can't be a `\mudimendef` command. Why Knuth didn't provide this kind of register, I don't know; but probably because `\mkern` and `\mskip` are not used so much that different registers for them are needed.

The chances to find `\mkern 3mu plus` in a document are, I believe, infinitesimal, but you can always test for `plus` after the specification, in case of `\mkern`.

There's no coercion either: `\mkern 3pt` is illegal, just like `\mkern 33`. In e-TeX there are `\mutoglue` and `\gluetomu` to do calculations (with `\glueexpr`) or comparisons (with `\ifdim`), but they simply transform 1mu into 1pt or vice versa. And code such as `\ifdim\mutoglue\mymuskip>\mydimen` is nonsensical, although legal.

For `\mkern` you could use `\afterassignment\DoSomethingForMKern\tempmuskip=`, but this, as you observe, will gobble a `plus` or `minus` part that might be hidden in a macro, but would stop the argument to `\mkern`, while the original token list would already be lost. Alas, I don't think it's really possible to do more than this.

Comment: I can't test anything _after_ the specification: the key with using `\afterassignment` is that I was letting TeX read tokens itself. Imagine parsing `\mkern\muskip\count\dimexpr 1pt/(\dimen0+3)\relax`... that's legal: `\dimen0` is coerced to an integer, added to `3`, divides `1pt` to give a value for `\dimexpr...\relax`, which in turn is coerced to an integer, hopefully small enough to be the number of a `\count` register, containing the value of the `\muskip` register to use (and coerce). Quite unfeasible :).

Comment: +1 for mentionning `\mutoglue`, and friends, though you could add `\muexpr`. Besides, I guess that `\mutoglue` was introduced precisely for use in `\ifdim` and the like.